# Поиск слова в массиве и замена?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой массив

```
const msgs = {
   success: [
      '223',
      '{text}',
      'success'
    ]
};
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как найти в массиве {text} и заменить его и после вернуть весь этот массив? Хочу его подставивть в `swal()`

Comment: У вас объект с ключом, в котором есть массив. Что именно не получается?

Comment: Ну я хочу найти {text} и заменить его и после передать этот объект в swal()

Comment: я хочу именно success

Comment: у меня просто ещё будет error

Comment: Вы хотите заменить элемент массива целиком? Или часть текста в элементе?

Comment: только хочу {text} заменить, чтобы потом передал msgs.success и было вот так swal(msgs.success) и вот нужно в нем найти {text} и заменить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод `indexOf` для поиска позиции элемента.

```
const replace = (arr, search, value) => {
  arr[arr.indexOf(search)] = value
  return arr
}

const msgs = {
  success: [
    '223',
    '{text}',
    'success'
  ]
}
msgs.success = replace(msgs.success, '{text}', 'Новое значение')
```

Comment: кхм... не хочет swal(replace(messages.error, '{text}', data.msg));

Comment: Class constructor wn cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: Откуда я знаю что такое swal, что такое data? Если вы хотите чтобы ответы учитывали эти переменные, добавьте их в вопрос!

Comment: `Class constructor wn cannot be invoked without 'new'` - это вообще не имеет никакого отношения к моему ответу

Comment: аа, ой! Должно быть типо так swal.fire('123', '{text}', 'success');

Comment: @jjjjj Там еще и new должно быть, раз это класс

Comment: не, там вот так swal.fire('hdhd', 'hdhd', 'success');